Error on Liquibase Authentication Attempt to BigQuery via GitHub Actions
Along with a small change log file, I have the following workflow YAML file in a GitHub repo:
name: Liquibase Update

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - deploy-to-bq-dev

jobs:
  test-liquibase-action:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Test Liquibase Update
    steps:

      - name: Create Private Key File
        env:
          GCP_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.LB_BQ_DEV_PRIVATE_KEY }}
        run: |
          pwd
          mkdir tmp
          echo "$GCP_PRIVATE_KEY" > /home/runner/work/BigQuery-Schema-Test/BigQuery-Schema-Test/tmp/privatekey.json
          echo "test contents"
          cd tmp
          realpath privatekey.json
      
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: liquibase-github-actions/update@v4.29.1
        with:
          changelogFile: 'db/changelog/db.changelog-master.sql'
          url: 'jdbc:bigquery://https://googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;ProjectId=dev;OAuthType=0;OAuthServiceAcctEmail=my_acct@dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com;OAuthPvtKeyPath=/home/runner/work/BigQuery-Schema-Test/BigQuery-Schema-Test/tmp/privatekey.json'
          driver: 'com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.Driver'

Running this in GitHub returns the following error:
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Connection could not be created to jdbc:bigquery://https://googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;ProjectId=dev;OAuthType=0;OAuthServiceAcctEmail=my_account@dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com;OAuthPvtKeyPath=/home/runner/work/BigQuery-Schema-Test/BigQuery-Schema-Test/tmp/privatekey.json with driver com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.Driver. [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100004) HttpTransport IO error : /home/runner/work/BigQuery-Schema-Test/BigQuery-Schema-Test/tmp/privatekey.json.

Please note that I added the last 3 lines of the “Create Private Key File” step for debugging purposes, i.e. to verify that the private key did indeed exist where I thought it would. And I was able to verify its location. So I’m not sure why this error is occurring.
